# Coding modern layouts with HTML and CSS

Tags: html, css

I've been working with web design since 2009 and now I'm having  a hard time with how to code modern layouts with HTML and CSS. I'll explain my question: when I began working with web design the process was to first create a mockup in Photoshop or Fireworks, and then look at the mockup to pick the measures, colors and eventual images that would be needed.

There was no problem in setting some element with a certain width because we planed just for one resolution. Resolutions below would need to scroll horizontally and resolutions above would see space with empty content. Also, if an element should be 20 pixels bellow another there was no problem setting a margin top and things like that.

Now there's all of that modern stuff from responsive design and so on, in which modern layouts should adapt to the resolutions. It seems kind of confusing then to keep working as I did in the past. Also, I've researched about CSS best practices and now I've found lots of things regarding less usage of ID's and more usage of classes and so on, things I've not seem when I started.

Are there some good resources like videos and tutorials that are good to get up to date with those modern practices?

Comment: Have you looked at, e.g., [Bootstrap](http://getbootstrap.com/)?

Comment: Get inspired - http://bradfrostweb.com/blog/post/7-habits-of-highly-effective-media-queries/

Comment: Things you should read.. http://alistapart.com/ and http://css-tricks.com/ and best of all http://tympanus.net/codrops/category/tutorials/. IDs have always been, and will always be used to identify an individual element, and classes are used to attribute characteristics to a set of common elements, so no they haven't changed.

Comment: Font-sizing of the new era - http://css-tricks.com/theres-more-to-the-css-rem-unit-than-font-sizing/ + CSS 3 http://lea.verou.me/css3-secrets/#intro

Answer (score 2):

I believe the short answer is "No." That's not helpful so I'll share some of what I have done that seems to be working.

I have been handling this by developing pages in the old same way, but now you also have to decide what the appropriate mobile version might look like. I typically start with making sure I am using this meta-tag in the header:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no">
```

Then the CSS has something like this:

```
body {width: 1000px; margin: 0 auto; }
@media only screen and (max-width: 600px) {
    body {width: auto; }
    /* All other mobile styles go here*/
    img.superfluous {display: none; }
}
```

This will take a floating fixed-width layout and turn it full screen when things get too scrunched. The mobile design is probably moving from a 3-column layout to a 1-column layout. Your most powerful tool is hiding as much superfluous graphics as you can. There is no room for that stuff on an iPhone. Then just stack all content on top of each other.

If you are the person developing the mockup I strongly encourage you to skip Photoshop and make the prototype right in HTML/CSS. That way you can work on the desktop and mobile versions simultaneously.

I honestly don't know what you've been reading but it worries me that it suggested to use less ids and more classes. That sounds like nonsense or worse, object-oriented CSS. Just keep focusing on writing maintainable and modular code.

Comment: Thanks for the help @protonfish, you're right I've read about this object-oriented css. I've saw some articles out there saying it's a css best practice. I found it very strange, but still I thought it was the way things were heading. I'm happy to see that isn't the case. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for the quality of my English before anything.
There are a certain number of resources available among which the website of Ethan Marcotte, the books of the creators of the French site alsacreation ... 
But also Twitter account to follow such as Hey Designer, CSS-Tricks, Hugo Giraudel, Tutorialzine Raphael Goetter… 
List is huge. Rest to follow industry news closely. 
Other technologies can also be interesting to use as Sass and Compass.